# C: undefined reference to function in another file

Tags: c

I am trying to call a C function that is defined in another file. I added the definition of the function to a header file and am including it in both .c files, but I am still receiving an error:

> C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyqsulH.o:
>
> In function `main':
>   C:DES_hash.c:42: undefined reference to`DES'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

Here is the function prototype definition:

```
/* DES_Utils.h */
#ifndef GUARD_DES_Utils /* prevents errors when including twice */
#define GUARD_DES_Utils

#include "DES.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
unsigned long long * DES(unsigned long long, unsigned long long);
....
#endif
```

Here is where the function is defined:

```
/* DES.c */
#include "DES_Utils.h"
unsigned long long * DES(unsigned long long plaintext, unsigned long long key)
{
  .....
}
```

Here is where I am trying to use it:

```
/* DES_hash.c */
#include "DES_Utils.h"
int main(int argc, int * argv)
{
    .....
        Ekp_i = DES(P_i ^ C_i, k); //<- line 42
    .....                          //P_i, C_i, and k are all unsigned long longs
}
```

**EDIT: Full Source (It is sort of large, sorry)**

DES.h:

```
 #ifndef GUARD_DES /* prevents errors when including twice */
 #define GUARD_DES

 #define NUM_ROUNDS 16
 /* 1. Data Encoding Permutations and Definitions */

 /* This macro defines the initial permutation, it will re-order the 
    64-bit message into this bit configuration
     Source: Stallings pg 80
     Note: all indices in this macro are 1 less than the table in Stallings
           because arrays are 0-based in C
  */
#define IP(x)  { x[57], x[49], x[41], x[33], x[25], x[17], x[9], x[1], \
                 x[59], x[51], x[43], x[35], x[27], x[19], x[11], x[3], \
             x[61], x[53], x[45], x[37], x[29], x[21], x[13], x[5], \
             x[63], x[55], x[47], x[39], x[31], x[23], x[15], x[7], \
             x[56], x[48], x[40], x[32], x[24], x[16], x[8],  x[0], \
             x[58], x[50], x[42], x[34], x[26], x[18], x[10], x[2], \
                 x[60], x[52], x[44], x[36], x[28], x[20], x[12], x[4], \
                 x[62], x[54], x[46], x[38], x[30], x[22], x[14], x[6] }

/* This macro defines the final permutation 
   Note: all numbers are off by 1 to support 0-based array indexing*/
#define IP_1(x) {
      x[39],  x[7],   x[47],    x[15],    x[55],   x[23],    x[63],   x[31], \
      x[38],  x[6],   x[46],    x[14],    x[54],   x[22],    x[62],   x[30], \
      x[37],  x[5],   x[45],    x[13],    x[53],   x[21],    x[61],   x[29], \
      x[36],  x[4],   x[44],    x[12],    x[52],   x[20],    x[60],   x[28], \
      x[35],  x[3],   x[43],    x[11],    x[51],   x[19],    x[59],   x[27], \
      x[34],  x[2],   x[42],    x[10],    x[50],   x[18],    x[58],   x[26], \
      x[33],  x[1],   x[41],    x[9],     x[49],   x[17],    x[57],   x[25], \
      x[32], x[0],   x[40],    x[8],     x[48],   x[16],    x[56],   x[24]} 

 /* This macro defines the expansion permutation, it takes an input of 
    32 bits; reorders these bits and reuses some bits in places,
     producing a 48-bit output
     Note: all numbers are off by 1 to support 0-based array indexing */
#define E(x) {   x[31],  x[0],  x[1],  x[2],   x[3],    x[4], \
                 x[3],   x[4],  x[5],  x[6],   x[7],    x[8], \
                 x[7],   x[8],  x[9],  x[10],  x[11],   x[12], \
                 x[11],  x[12], x[13], x[14],  x[15],   x[16], \
                 x[15],  x[16], x[17], x[18],  x[19],   x[20], \
                 x[19],  x[20], x[21], x[22],  x[23],   x[24], \
                 x[23],  x[24], x[25], x[26],  x[27],   x[28], \
                 x[27],  x[28], x[29], x[30],  x[31],   x[0] }

 /* This macro defines the Permutation function P which shuffles a 32 
    bit array 
    Note: all numbers are off by 1 to support 0-based array indexing */
#define P(x) {  x[15],  x[6],   x[19],  x[20], \
                x[28],  x[11],  x[27],  x[16], \
                x[0],   x[14],  x[22],  x[25], \
                x[4],   x[17],  x[30],  x[9], \
                x[1],   x[7],   x[23],  x[13], \
                x[31],  x[26],  x[2],   x[8],  \
                x[18],  x[12],  x[29],  x[5],  \
                x[21],  x[10],  x[3],   x[24]}

 /* These Matrix definitions are for the S boxes */
  #define SBOX_ROWS 4
  #define SBOX_COLS 16

   int SBOX_1[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  { 
   {14,  4,  13,  1,   2, 15,  11,  8,   3, 10,  6, 12,  5,  9,   0,  7},
   { 0, 15,   7,  4,  14,  2,  13,  1,  10,  6, 12, 11,  9,  5,   3,  8},
   { 4,  1,  14,  8,  13,  6,   2, 11,  15, 12,  9,  7,  3, 10,   5,  0},
   {15, 12,   8,  2,   4,  9,   1,  7,   5, 11,  3, 14,  10, 0,   6, 13}};

   int SBOX_2[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   {15,  1,   8, 14,   6, 11,   3,  4,   9,  7,   2, 13,  12,  0,   5, 10},
   { 3, 13,   4,  7,  15,  2,   8, 14,  12,  0,   1, 10,   6,  9,  11,  5},
   { 0, 14,   7, 11,  10,  4,  13,  1,   5,  8,  12,  6,   9,  3,   2, 15},
   {13,  8,  10,  1,   3, 15,   4,  2,  11,  6,   7, 12,   0,  5,  14,  9}};

   int SBOX_3[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   {10,  0,   9, 14,   6,  3,  15,  5,   1, 13,  12,  7,  11,  4,   2,  8},
   {13,  7,   0,  9,   3,  4,   6, 10,   2,  8,   5, 14,  12, 11,  15,  1},
   {13,  6,   4,  9,   8, 15,   3,  0,  11,  1,   2, 12,   5, 10,  14,  7},
   {1,  10,  13,  0,   6,  9,   8,  7,   4, 15,  14,  3,  11,  5,   2, 12}};

   int SBOX_4[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   { 7, 13,  14,  3,   0,  6,   9, 10,   1,  2,   8,  5,  11, 12,   4, 15},
   {13,  8,  11,  5,   6, 15,   0,  3,   4,  7,   2, 12,   1, 10,  14,  9},
   {10,  6,   9,  0,  12, 11,   7, 13,  15,  1,   3, 14,   5,  2,   8,  4},
   { 3, 15,   0,  6,  10,  1,  13,  8,   9,  4,   5, 11,  12,  7,   2, 14}};

   int SBOX_5[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   {2,  12,   4,  1,   7, 10,  11,  6,   8,  5,   3,  15,  13,  0,  14,  9},
   {14, 11,   2, 12,   4,  7,  13,  1,   5,  0,  15,  10,   3,  9,   8,  6},
   {4,   2,   1, 11,  10, 13,   7,  8,  15,  9,  12,   5,   6,  3,   0, 14},
   {11,  8,  12,  7,   1, 14,   2, 13,   6, 15,   0,   9,  10,  4,   5,  3}};

   int SBOX_6[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   {12,  1,  10, 15,   9,  2,   6,  8,   0, 13,   3,  4,  14,  7,   5, 11},
   {10, 15,   4,  2,   7, 12,   9,  5,   6,  1,  13, 14,   0, 11,   3,  8},
   { 9, 14,  15,  5,   2,  8,  12,  3,   7,  0,   4, 10,   1, 13,  11,  6},
   { 4,  3,   2, 12,   9,  5,  15, 10,  11, 14,   1,  7,   6,  0,   8, 13}};

   int SBOX_7[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   { 4, 11,   2, 14,  15,  0,   8, 13,   3, 12,   9,  7,   5, 10,   6,  1},
   {13,  0,  11,  7,   4,  9,   1, 10,  14,  3,   5, 12,   2, 15,   8,  6},
   { 1,  4,  11, 13,  12,  3,   7, 14,  10, 15,   6,  8,   0,  5,   9,  2},
   { 6, 11,  13,  8,   1,  4,  10,  7,   9,  5,   0, 15,  14,  2,   3, 12}};

   int SBOX_8[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  {
   {13,  2,   8,  4,   6, 15,  11,  1,  10,  9,   3, 14,   5,  0,  12,  7},
   { 1, 15,  13,  8,  10,  3,   7,  4,  12,  5,   6, 11,   0, 14,   9,  2},
   { 7, 11,   4,  1,   9, 12,  14,  2,   0,  6,  10, 13,  15,  3,   5,  8},
   { 2,  1,  14,  7,   4, 10,   8, 13,  15, 12,   9,  0,   3,  5,   6, 11}};


 /* 2. Subkey Generation Permutations and Definitions*/

 /* This macro defines Permuted Choice#1, it reorders and reduces the input 
     64-bit key to 56 bits, Note: all numbers are off by 
     1 to support 0-based array indexing */
#define PC_1(x) { x[56], x[48],  x[40],  x[32],  x[24],  x[16],  x[8],  \
                  x[0],  x[57],  x[49],  x[41],  x[33],  x[25],  x[17], \
                  x[9],  x[1],   x[58],  x[50],  x[42],  x[34],  x[26], \
                  x[18], x[10],  x[2],   x[59],  x[51],  x[43],  x[35], \
                  x[62], x[54],  x[46],  x[38],  x[30],  x[22],  x[14], \
                  x[6],  x[61],  x[53],  x[45],  x[37],  x[29],  x[21], \
                  x[13], x[5],   x[60],  x[52],  x[44],  x[36],  x[28], \
              x[20], x[12],  x[4],   x[27],  x[19],  x[11],  x[3]  }

/* This macro defines Permuted Choice#2, it reorders and reduces the input
   56-bit key to 48 bits
    Note: all numbers are off by 1 to support 0-based array indexing */
#define PC_2(x) { x[13],  x[16],  x[10],  x[23],  x[0],   x[4],  \
                  x[2],   x[27],  x[14],  x[5],   x[20],  x[9], \
                  x[22],  x[18],  x[11],  x[3],   x[25],  x[7],  \
                  x[15],  x[6],   x[26],  x[19],  x[12],  x[1],  \
                  x[40],  x[51],  x[30],  x[36],  x[46],  x[54], \
                  x[29],  x[39],  x[50],  x[44],  x[32],  x[47], \
                  x[43],  x[48],  x[38],  x[55],  x[33],  x[52], \
                  x[45],  x[41],  x[49],  x[35],  x[28],  x[31] }

/* This array defines the number of left shifts to perform
   at round i */
   #define NUM_LEFTSHIFTS 16
   int LEFTSHIFT_SCHEDULE[NUM_LEFTSHIFTS] = {1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1};
#endif
```

DES_Utils.h:

```
/* McMillen_DES_Utils.h
 * This header file holds the functions that do 
 * the majority of the work for my program. I abstracted
 * them from the main C file to avoid excess clutter
 *
 * Hunter McMillen
 * 2/9/2012
 */ 
 #ifndef GUARD_DES_Utils /* prevents errors when including twice */
 #define GUARD_DES_Utils


 #include "DES.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 //Definition of shared function !!
 unsigned long long * DES(unsigned long long plaintext, unsigned long long key);

  /* Counts the number of bits it
   * takes to represent an integer a
   */
   int num_bits(unsigned long long a)
   {
      int bitCount = 0;

      while(a > 0)
      {
         bitCount++;
         a = a >> 1; //shift to the right 1 bit
      }

      return bitCount;
   }

   /* Converts from an unsigned long long into an array of 
       integers that form the binary representation of a */
   void ull_to_bin_array(unsigned long long a, int *b, int length)
   {
      int *temp = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

      int i;
      for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
         temp[i] = (a >> i) & 1; //store the ith bit in temp[i]
      }

      for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         int tLen = (length - 1) - i; //mapping from temp[i] -> b[i]
         b[i] = temp[tLen]; 
         //store the (length - i)th of temp in b[i], this puts the MSB first
      }
   }

   unsigned long long * bin_string_to_ull(char * bin_string)
   {
    //allocate space for a pointe to an ull
      unsigned long long * out = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long));
    //interpret bin_string as a 64-bit number
      unsigned long long t = strtoull(bin_string, NULL, 2);

    //copy the address of t into out
      out = &t;

      return out;
   }

    /* prints a one-dimensional array given
       a pointer to it, and its length, and optionally a header */
   void print_array(int *arr, int length, char *msg)
   {
      int i;
      if(msg != NULL) printf("%s: ",msg);
      for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         printf("%d", arr[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }    

    /**
     * Takes an input of a 4 element character array
     * that represents a half-byte in binary, maps
     * the 4-bit value to the appropriate hex character
     */
   void map_bin_to_hex(char *c)
   {
      char hexMap[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      int index = strtoull(c, NULL, 2);
      printf("%c", hexMap[index]);
   }

    /**
     * Takes a 64 element integer array that holds 
     * the binary representation of a 64-bit hex number
     */
   void bin_array_to_hex(int *b, int length)
   {
      int i, j, k;

    //read 4 bits 16 times
      for(i = 0; i < length; i+=4)
      {
         char hexB[5];
         for(k = 0, j = i; j < (i+4); j++, k++)
         {
            hexB[k] = b[j] + '0';
            //printf("h[%d] = %d\n", k, hexB[k]);
         }
         hexB[5] = '\0';
         map_bin_to_hex(hexB);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

    /**
     * Takes as input an integer array containing the binary 
     * representation of some number N, and converts all the 
     * bits of N to characters then compresses
     * them into a single "string"
     */ 
   char * bin_array_to_string(int *b, int length)
   {
    //allocate space for length characters
      char *string = malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));

      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         string[i] = b[i] + '0';
      }
      string[length] = '\0';

      return string;
   }

    /** 
     * This function takes as input the binary representation
     * of a 64-bit integer held in array form, and partitions it 
     * into LEFT and RIGHT halves
     */
   void partition_arrays(int *s, int *l, int *r, int length)
   {
      int pLength = length / 2;
      int i, j;

      for(i = 0; i < pLength; i++)
      {
         l[i] = s[i];
      }

      for(i = pLength, j = 0; i < length - 1; i++, j++)
      {
         r[j] = s[i];
      }
   }

   /**
     * Takes two arrays of equals length and concatenates their 
     * contents using memcpy 
     */
   int * concatenate_arrays(int *a, int *b, int length)
   {    
      int aLen = length * sizeof(int);
      int bLen = length * sizeof(int);      
      //allocate enough space in the new array for both arrays a and b
      int *new = malloc((aLen + bLen) * sizeof(int));

      memcpy(new, a, aLen);
      memcpy(new + length, b, bLen);

      return new;
   }

    /**
     * Given an integer array and a character array, this function
     * converts the character array to an integer then XORs the two arrays
     * contents
     */
   int * xor_arrays(int *a, char *b, int length)
   {
    //alocate enough space in the xor array 
      int *xor = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         xor[i] = a[i] ^ (b[i] - '0'); 
         //compute xor, subtract '0' to convert from char to int
      }

      return xor;
   }

    /**
     * Same as the above function but for two integer arrays, 
     * their contents are XORed and returned in another array
     */
   int * xor_int_arrays(int *a, int *b, int length)
   {
    //alocate enough space in the xor array 
      int *xor = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         xor[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]; //compute xor
      }

      return xor;
   }

    /**
     * Given an array and its length, this function will compute 
     * the results of ALL of the SBOXs for this array
     * The result that is returned is an integer array consisting 
     * of the results from the SBOXs
     */
   int * compute_sbox(int *a, int length)
   {
    /* bits needed for each sbox */
      int sbox_length  = length / 8;
    /* holds integer values retrieved from the SBOX */
      int sbox_results[8]; 
      /* two indices for each sbox */
      int *sbox_indices = malloc(sbox_length * sizeof(int));

    /* i counts every 6 bits in the array 
       k processes bits from 0 - 6 in the inner loop
       j is used to copy values properly into the sbox char array
       y indicates what SBOX we are taking a value from */
      int i, k, j, y;

    /* read 6 bits 8 times */
      for(i = 0, y = 0; i < length; i += sbox_length, y++)
      {
         char sbox[7];
        /* grab every 6 elements of the array */
         for(k = 0, j = i; j < (i + sbox_length); k++, j++)
         {
            sbox[k] = a[j] + '0'; //convert to a string
         }
         sbox[7] = '\0'; //append the null terminator

        /* compute the row and column index */
         char rows[3];
         rows[0] = sbox[0];
         rows[1] = sbox[5];
         rows[2] = '\0';

         char cols[5];
         cols[0] = sbox[1];
         cols[1] = sbox[2];
         cols[2] = sbox[3];
         cols[3] = sbox[4];
         cols[4] = '\0';

        /* get indices into the SBOXy+1 */
         int row = strtoull(rows, NULL, 2);
         int col = strtoull(cols, NULL, 2); 

        /* switch over y and get the results from the SBOXs */
         switch(y)
         {
            case 0:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_1[row][col];
               break;   
            case 1:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_2[row][col];
               break;   
            case 2:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_3[row][col];
               break;   
            case 3:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_4[row][col];
               break;   
            case 4:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_5[row][col];
               break;   
            case 5:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_6[row][col];
               break;   
            case 6:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_7[row][col];
               break;   
            case 7:
               sbox_results[y] = SBOX_8[row][col];
               break;       
            default:
               break;   
         }
      }

    /* at this point we have processed every 6 bits in the array 
       and retrieved the correct values from the SBOXs, 
       all that remains is to convert the 
       results to arrays and concatenate them */

    /* initialize arrays */
      int SBOX_1_Result[4]; int SBOX_5_Result[4];
      int SBOX_2_Result[4]; int SBOX_6_Result[4];
      int SBOX_3_Result[4]; int SBOX_7_Result[4];
      int SBOX_4_Result[4]; int SBOX_8_Result[4];

    /* fill the arrays */
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[0], SBOX_1_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[1], SBOX_2_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[2], SBOX_3_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[3], SBOX_4_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[4], SBOX_5_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[5], SBOX_6_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[6], SBOX_7_Result, 4);
      ull_to_bin_array(sbox_results[7], SBOX_8_Result, 4);

    /* concatenate the arrays in pairs, since my concatenate function above
       requires equal length inputs */
      int *first_2  = concatenate_arrays(SBOX_1_Result, SBOX_2_Result, 4);
      int *second_2 = concatenate_arrays(SBOX_3_Result, SBOX_4_Result, 4);
      int *third_2  = concatenate_arrays(SBOX_5_Result, SBOX_6_Result, 4);
      int *last_2   = concatenate_arrays(SBOX_7_Result, SBOX_8_Result, 4);

    /* combine the two halves */
      int *first_half = concatenate_arrays(first_2, second_2, 8);
      int *second_half = concatenate_arrays(third_2, last_2, 8);

    /* combine into one full array */
      int *full = concatenate_arrays(first_half, second_half, 16);

      return full;
   }

    /* Reverses the elements in array a
      from index start to end */
   void reverse(int *a, int start, int end)
   {
      int swap;
      while(start < end)
      {
         swap         = a[start];
         a[start++]   = a[--end];
         a[end]       = swap;
      }
   }

    /**
     * Uses a triple-reversal method of left-shifting
     * that is described here: 
     * http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02b.pdf
     * takes as input, a pointer to an array, 
     * the length of that array and the amount
     * to left shift by
     */
   void left_shift(int *a, int aLen, int amt)
   {
    //left shift a by amt using three reversals
      reverse(a, 0, amt);
      reverse(a, amt, aLen);
      reverse(a, 0, aLen);
   }
#endif
```

DES.c:

```
 #include "DES.h"
 #include "DES_Utils.h"

 /* Global Definintions */
   char *keys[16]; //array of keys for all 16 rounds

 /* This function takes as input the initial 64-bit key
  * It generates all 16 subkeys for rounds
  * 1 - 16 and stores them in the global keys[] array
  */
   void generate_subkeys(int key[])
   {
      /* uses the macro permutation defined in
      McMillen_DES.h to permute the initial key into
      a 56-bit key */
      int PC1_Key[] = PC_1(key);

      //split the permuted PC_1 key into two halves 
      //C and D using pointer arithmetic
      int *C0 = PC1_Key;
      int *D0 = PC1_Key + 28;
      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROUNDS; i++)
      {
         /* left shift C0 and DO by the amount 
            indicated in the left shift schedule defined in McMillen_DES.h */
         left_shift(C0, 28, LEFTSHIFT_SCHEDULE[i]);
         left_shift(D0, 28, LEFTSHIFT_SCHEDULE[i]);

         /* merge the shifted Ci and Di together, 
            where i is the round number */
         int *temp = concatenate_arrays(C0, D0, 28);

        /* pass temp to the Permuted Choice 2 macro, 
           which will reduce it from 56-bits
           to 48-bits and generate Ki, the key for round i */
         int Ki[] = PC_2(temp);

        /* compress the binary array into a string for storage */
         char *keyi = bin_array_to_string(Ki, 48);

        /* store the string key for round i */
         keys[i] = keyi;
      }    
   }

    /** 
     * This functions handles the encryption functionality
     * of the DES algorithm.
     */
   void encrypt(int plaintext[])
   {
    /* permute the plaintext message with the IP */
      int permuted_pt[] = IP(plaintext);

    /* partition the permuted plaintext into two halves using pointers */
      int *Li = permuted_pt;
      int *Ri = permuted_pt + 32;

      int i;
      for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROUNDS; i++) 
      {
         /* pass Ri into the Expansion permutation to 
            expand it from 32 to 48 bits */
         int e_Ri[] = E(Ri);

         /* XOR the expanded Ri and Ki, the key for this round i */
         int *xorKeyi_Ri = xor_arrays(e_Ri, keys[i], 48);

         /* parses the row and column indices from the xor'd key and E(Ri)
         then gets the value at that position in SBOXi and concatenates
        the results together */
         int *sbox = compute_sbox(xorKeyi_Ri, 48);

        /* apply the permutation P to the result from the SBOXs */
         int permuted_sbox[] = P(sbox);

        /* use a temp variable to store Ri, update Ri, 
               then assign the old Ri to Li */
         int *temp = Ri;
         Ri = xor_int_arrays(Li, permuted_sbox, 32); 
         /* Ri = L(i-1) XOR f(R(i-1), Ki) */
         Li = temp; /* Li = R(i-1) */
      }

    /* swap the two halves so Ri comes first */
      int *encrypted = concatenate_arrays(Ri, Li, 32);
    /* apply the final permutation */
      int fp[] = IP_1(encrypted);
    /* print the hex result of the final permutation to the console */
      bin_array_to_hex(fp, 64);
   }

   /**
     * Encrypts a 64-plaintext value using a 64-bit key
     * held as unsigned long long values
     */
   unsigned long long * DES(unsigned long long plaintext, 
                            unsigned long long key)
   {
      /* initialize arrays with 64 positions that will hold the 
         binary representation of the key and plaintext, 
         initialized to all 0's */
      int key_arr[64] = { 0 };
      int pt_arr[64]  = { 0 };

      /* fill the arrays with the binary representations
         of the plaintext and the key */
      ull_to_bin_array(key, key_arr, 64);
      ull_to_bin_array(plaintext, pt_arr, 64);

      /* generate subkeys for all 16 rounds */
      generate_subkeys(key_arr);

      /* encrypt the plaintext, this function will display the hex results */
      encrypt(pt_arr);
   }
```

DES_hash.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "DES_Utils.h"

   char * strToHex(const char * input);

   int main(int argc, int * argv)
   {
    /* initialize they key and IV (C sub 0)*/
      unsigned long long k   = strtoull("0123456789ABCDEF", NULL, 16);
      unsigned long long C_i = strtoull("00FF11EE22DD33CC", NULL, 16); 
      unsigned long long P_i;
      unsigned long long * Ekp_i;

      char buffer[9]; //holds 8 characters read from  the file (i.e. 64-bits)
      char * plaintext;
      FILE *f;

      if (f = fopen("input2.txt", "rb"))
      {
         while( fread(buffer, 8, 1, f) != 0)
         {
            buffer[8] = '\0';

            /* convert the ascii string input into a 64-bit hex string */
            plaintext = strToHex(buffer);
            /* convert the hex string into a 64 bit unsigned long long value */
            P_i = strtoull(plaintext, NULL, 16);

            Ekp_i = DES(P_i ^ C_i, k);
            C_i   = *(Ekp_i);

            printf("%s\n", plaintext);
            printf("%llu\n", P_i);
            printf("%llu\n", C_i);
            printf("%llX\n\n", P_i ^ C_i);
            break;
         }
         fclose(f);
      }
   }

    /**
     * Converts an array with ascii strings in it
     * to its corresponding hex value, this will double
     * the size of the input because one ascii character
     * is two hex bits
     */
   char * strToHex(const char * input)
   {
      char *output = malloc((strlen(input) * 2) + 1);
      char * o = output;

      int i;
      for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; o += 2, i++)
      {
         sprintf(o, "%02X", input[i]);
      }

    // don't forget to free output!
      return output;
   }
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: when you link then you have to supply the object files of both .c files

Comment: I am compiling and linking inside of an IDE called jGrasp using the mingw compiler.

Comment: There is much confusion here with functions defined in "header" files which are then included into two sources. This won't link.

Comment: @blueshift Can you explain why it won't link? I have guards defined in the header files, so they should only be included once.

Comment: Only once - in each source file. So you'll end up with a copy of the functions in each source file, and they conflict when you try to build it (I tried).

Comment: @blueshift How can i resolve the conflict then? I thought that was the point of the include guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a number of things to get it to compile. Some of these points are only to get rid of warnings. :

1. Add \ to line 24 of DES.h #define IP_1(x) { \
2. In DES_Utils.h, line 228: Here sbox_indices are defined, and malloc'd but 
   never freed NOR used.
3. Correct signature of main should/could be int main(void /* int argc, char *argv[] */), 
   Inserted void as argument's are not used.
4. Add in main() parenteses around f = fopen() statement.
   <strike>**Here you should check for read bytes and not != 0.** If file is mismatch in sizeof(unsigned long long) / CHAR_BIT you'd be working on "tail" from previous read.</strike>
5. DES_Utils.h: Added signatures of shared functions, moved rest to new file DES_Utils.c

Modified DES_Utils.h:

```
#ifndef GUARD_DES_Utils /* prevents errors when including twice */
#define GUARD_DES_Utils

//Definition of shared function !!
unsigned long long *DES(unsigned long long, unsigned long long);
void left_shift(int *, int, int);
int *concatenate_arrays(int *, int *, int);
char *bin_array_to_string(int *, int);

int *xor_arrays(int *, char *, int);
int *compute_sbox(int *, int);
int *xor_int_arrays(int *, int *, int);
void bin_array_to_hex(int *, int);

void ull_to_bin_array(unsigned long long, int *, int);

#endif
```

6) Moved

```
#define NUM_LEFTSHIFTS 16
int LEFTSHIFT_SCHEDULE[NUM_LEFTSHIFTS] = {1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1};
```

from DES.h to DES.c

7) Moved

```
#define SBOX_ROWS 4
#define SBOX_COLS 16
```

and all int SBOX_N's to DES_Utils.c

```
int SBOX_1[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  { ...
trough
int SBOX_8[SBOX_ROWS][SBOX_COLS] =  { ...
```

8) Compile:

Objects:

```
gcc -c -o obj/DES_Hash.o src/DES_Hash.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -ggdb
gcc -c -o obj/DES_Utils.o src/DES_Utils.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -ggdb
gcc -c -o obj/DES.o src/DES.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -ggdb
```

Link:

```
gcc -o ./bin/DES_Hash ./obj/DES_Hash.o ./obj/DES_Utils.o ./obj/DES.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -ggdb
```

9) function DES in DES.c does not return any value, but try to run anyway.

```
73FB90EEDF18B09A
SIGSEGV
```

File structure after compile:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── DES_Hash
├── obj
│   ├── DES_Hash.o
│   ├── DES.o
│   └── DES_Utils.o
├── src
│   ├── DES.c
│   ├── DES.h
│   ├── DES_Hash.c
│   ├── DES_Utils.c
│   └── DES_Utils.h
└── test
    └── input2.txt
```

**EDIT:** Note to point 4. Consider using something like:

```
#define BYTE_ULL  (sizeof(unsigned long long))

char buffer[BYTE_ULL + 1];
fread  BYTE_ULL bytes
buffer[BYTE_ULL] = '\0';
```

And check read bytes instead of != 0, or use as now but say == 1 instead.

**EDIT2:** In DES_Utils.c (aprox line 136), bin_array_to_hex():

Here byte 4 in hexB are never set, thus call to strtoull() in map_bin_to_hex() result in work on an unitialized value.

As mentioned in pt 9 and comment below, DES() does not return any value thus resulting in SIGSEGV in main() when trying to give C_i the value of Ekp_i, which never receives a pointer from DES().

There is only *one* free(), so valgrind gives a rather filled list (here is two frees as I added a dummy value of 1234 from DES() and frees that):

```
==31352== Command: bin/DES_Hash
==31352== 
73FB90EEDF18B09A
74657374696E6720
8387236824869660448
1234
74657374696E63F2

==31352== 
==31352== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31352==     in use at exit: 48,417 bytes in 308 blocks
==31352==   total heap usage: 310 allocs, 2 frees, 48,777 bytes allocated
==31352== 
==31352== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31352==    definitely lost: 47,633 bytes in 292 blocks
==31352==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31352==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31352==    still reachable: 784 bytes in 16 blocks
==31352==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Use of valgrind with --leak-check=full gives all locations to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, I actually did a lot of what you did i response to Michael's post. This was very helpful/

Comment: Glad to help :), The SIGSEGV is beacuse of C_i = *(Ekp_i);, in main(). Ekp_i is "set - but not set" by previous line Ekp_i = DES(P_i ^ C_i, k);, Since DES does not return any value, as noted in pt 9, Ekp_i is null. Hence trying to set C_i to a value of an uninitialized ull.

Answer (score 1):

You include *before* GUARD_DES_Utils.

```
/* DES_Utils.h */
#include "DES.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef GUARD_DES_Utils /* prevents errors when including twice */
...
```

Move includes to body of incl. guards.

Comment: When I do this I get multiple definition errors even though I have guards in both of my header files.

Comment: There are only 4 files, no external libraries, and I didn't create a make file. There are two C files, and two header files all in the same directory.

Comment: includes bellow /* DES_Utils.h */ must be inside these guards.

Comment: can u by any chance post full sources?

Comment: It is pretty large, but yes I will post it above as there has to be a mistake in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to compile just `DES_hash.c`, the linker will complain with

```
In function main': C:DES_hash.c:42: undefined reference to DES'
```

which is only natural since `DES()` is defined in `DES.c`, and you are not including it in the linking process. Now, what you must do is, of course, compile like `gcc DES.c DES_hash.c`; however you've made a boo-boo: you have defined functions inside a header file (`DES_Utils.h`). What that means, is that those functions are defined whenever something includes `DES_Utils.h`, which is bad. In this particular case, some functions are defined in both `DES_hash.c` and `DES.c`, and the linker is confused, not knowing which one to link against.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to move the function definitions from `DES_Utils.h` to a new file `DES_Utils.c`, leaving only the declarations of a public interface in the header. Also, make sure the arrays you define in `DES.h` are either `static` to the header if needed in multiple `.c` files or defined in a single `.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

I work in Linux and GCC but I hope it will help:

for me it looks like you don't link it statically, so the main code requires to load libraries on runtime. Link it statically, if possible, or make the used library visible for your code (in Linux you could set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, in W. I have no idea)